# Advice on submission of a paper.

Tags: journals, advice

Dear all,

I just received a letter from editors of  one of top journals, saying 
"Though the expert consulted felt that your paper, "is a solid paper," 
the expert did not recommend publication in the journal."

It is my first paper and it is a situation that I may not expect a guidance from my advisor for submission.

The only reason I chose the top journal is that I have no idea about this matter and wanted to  learn the reality.

Now, I am a little puzzled in understanding the response from the editors. What does it mean by "solid paper"? Can I be encouraged to submit my paper to another top journal, or  is  it just a common expression to be used in rejection?

Thank you for your concern. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Solid paper means: should be published somewhere, just not in Annals/JAMS/Acta/Inventiones. My advice is: write to the editor, tell him you are new at this, and maybe you could ask him/referee what their journal suggestion is. 

On the other hand, this is not really an appropriate question for MO...

Comment: Related questions have been asked on MO before - if you haven't already seen them, you might wish to look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7284/how-to-select-a-journal http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19065/when-your-paper-makes-a-borderline-case-for-a-top-journal http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3512/top-specialized-journals http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42/which-are-the-best-mathematics-journals-and-what-are-the-differences-bet

Comment: They're saying your paper is good, but for whatever reason it's not right for that journal at that time.  There's many reasons they may have rejected it: the journal is focusing more on different topics at the moment, perhaps your result is too specialized for a general audience, etc.    

Comment: The one distinction to be made is that it was not sent for a full referee report. The journal has excessive backlog at this time and is "pre-screening." So this is not entirely the same as a rejection by someone who really sat down and went through line by line. My experience in the same situation is that the expert may not be willing to spend the time for a more detailed report, or if some more detail is supplied it may never get back to you.  

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I will take the advice by Igor Rivin. I am afraid that it may be the situation described by Will Jagy. In that case, I guess I may not get any suggestion from them. But I will still try. 


Comment: If you are the only author, it is up to you how long to wait on possible advice from the first journal. In my case it was a co-author, and a misunderstanding, and several months wasted. For you, getting well-informed individual advice, something MO cannot do, may be more important than the time it takes.

Comment: I strongly recommend you seek advice from someone who knows you personally and is familiar with your field. I always asked my thesis advisor (and others) this and I always got good advice.